# What's best way to implement Global Search (search in multiple collections) in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to add global search which will search in a few collections (e.g. clients, orders, projects...) and put all the answers in one list.

I already looked at `EasySearch` and `meteorhacks:search-source` but they support search only in one collection at the time.

Is somebody already solving this problem? What would be best way to start?

Comment: does a for loop not work? not sure what you are trying to accomplish but merging multiple result arrays shouldn't be too hard

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the data? There may be a number of good options but it's hard to tell. Do you have some common keys among all of those you'd like to search against? Or are you looking for full text search?

Comment: Probably my main point was to ask if somebody already implemented some good solution for search in multiple collections at once like `EasySearch` package does for search in one collection. Also probably somebody already did it with my mentioned packages as has good suggestions.

Sure, I can implement my own search using ElasticSearch or Mongos own search, but why create own if somebody did it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days of research finally I findout that `EasySearch` so provide search on multiple collections, it was just hidden in documentation.

All what was needed was:

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('collection1', {
   'field' : ['name'],
   'collection' : Collection1,
   'use' : 'minimongo',
   'limit' : 20,
});

EasySearch.createSearchIndex('collection2', {
   'field' : ['name', 'text'],
   'collection' : Collection2,
   'use' : 'minimongo',
   'limit' : 20,
});

Template.yourTemplate.indexes = ['players', 'cars'];
```

HTML

```
<div class="search-input">
     <!-- indexes is a javascript array which holds 'players' and 'cars' -->
     {{> esInput index=indexes placeholder="Search..." }}
</div>

<div class="results-wrapper">
     {{#esEach index="players"}}
         {{> player}}
     {{/esEach}}

     {{#esEach index="cars"}}
         {{> car}}
     {{/esEach}}
</div>
```

Also I suggest to read discussion in this issue: https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/10

---

> Update after EasySearch changed their API. Now you should do:

```
Collection1Index = EasySearch.Index({
   'collection': Collection1,
   'fields': ['name', 'description'],
   'engine': new EasySearch.MongoDB()
});

Collection2Index = EasySearch.Index({
   'collection': Collection2,
   'fields': ['name', 'text'],
   'engine': new EasySearch.MongoDB()
});

Template.yourTemplate.helpers ({
    indexes: function() { return [Collection1Index, Collection2Index] }
    attributes: function() { return {placeholder: "Search clients, orders and suppliers...", class: 'form-control'} }
    Collection1Index: function () { return Collection1Index }
    Collection2Index: function () { return Collection2Index }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="search-input">
     {{> EasySearch.Input indexes=indexes attributes=attributes }}
</div>

<div class="results-wrapper">
     {{#EasySearch.Each index=Collection1Index}}
         {{> player}}
     {{/EasySearch.Each}}

     {{#EasySearch.Each index=Collection2Index}}
         {{> car}}
     {{/EasySearch.Each}}
</div>
```

Comment: I can't get searching over multiple indexes to work and I think the API has changed, for example it's now EasySearch.Input instead of esInput. All I get is an error "Error: Did not receive an index or an array of indexes: "[object Object],[object Object]" [invalid-configuration]". I've read the discussion of the issue but can't figure this out. Using "indexes=indexes" just gives me a different error! Can anybody post a working example using the new API?

Comment: I just added updated example which works for me with newest EasySearch changes.

Comment: I think {{> EasySearch indexes=indexes attributes=attributes }} needs to be {{> EasySearch.Input indexes=indexes attributes=attributes }}?

Comment: It should be "Collection1Index = new EasySearch.Index" instead of "Collection1Index = EasySearch.Index"